# Should we try to use css sprite as much as possible?

Tags: css

Can we use whole page design jpg file as css-sprite without slicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Most designs includes one or more images which are:

Content images, which should be included with `<img>` and have suitable alt text.

and/or

Images which tile in 2 dimensions, which can't be sprited.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it generally requires a lot of planning and careful development. For example, if you need to add a new icon/image to a page and you suddenly find your sprite image is not big enough, you have to go through and change *all* images on the page to use whatever new layout you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by codeka, you can. but you'll end up with a really big .jpg with a lot of white space if you plan to use the whole page as a sprite without slicing

Answer (score 0):

You also probably don't want to use jpg for everything.  Some things are better with jpg, some with png (or gif).